# RecyclerView LinearLayoutManager set item count

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In GridLayoutManager i am able to set span count and that makes the items inside the view to resize to be able to fit that span count horizontally.

I have a LinearLayoutManager and i want to use it the same way, have a fixed number of items visible and resize them to fit.

I use both linear and grid on same view and shows items depending of the screen size. I can't seem to find a way to get both layouts showing the same amount of items.

Comment: Needs more explanation.

Comment: I have a recyclerview that show's 3 items in a GroupLayout. The items are sized acording with the screen with automaticly by the layout. But if i use a Linear layout the item are sized acording to their own content. I think i might need a custom layout that resizes the items

Answer (score 9):

### UPDATED

My previous answer was to use ItemsAdapter to set each items width, from the code design stand point this is not the best solution.
Proper way to do that is to extend LinearLayoutManager, since it is LayoutManager responsibility to layout item views.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/modjke/b652021679a2ed1935645a18102ab799

Code:

```
//usage: 
//int itemsPerPage = 7;
//layoutManager = new LinearLayoutPagerManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false, itemsPerPage);
//recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
public class LinearLayoutPagerManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

private int mItemsPerPage;

public int getItemsPerPage()
{
    return mItemsPerPage;
}


public LinearLayoutPagerManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout, int itemsPerPage) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);

    mItemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
}

@Override
public boolean checkLayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp) {
    return super.checkLayoutParams(lp) && lp.width == getItemSize();
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
    return setProperItemSize(super.generateDefaultLayoutParams());
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp) {
    return setProperItemSize(super.generateLayoutParams(lp));
}

private RecyclerView.LayoutParams setProperItemSize(RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp) {
    int itemSize = getItemSize();
    if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
        lp.width = itemSize;
    } else {
        lp.height = itemSize;
    }
    return lp;
}

private int getItemSize() {
    int pageSize = getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL ? getWidth() : getHeight();
    return Math.round((float) pageSize / mItemsPerPage);
}
```

}

### PREVIOUS ANSWER

You can set exact item count in your adapter by providing a width for each item. This works only if all your items have equal width, do not forget to set

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

on your RecyclerView

```
final static int ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 7;

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    int itemWidth = parent.getWidth() / ITEMS_PER_PAGE;

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.your_layout, parent, false);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = itemView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width = itemWidth;
    itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    return new ItemViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution for making one-lined scrollable list with same items weight. GridLayotManager doesn't allow to do it because after width exceeding it goes for the second line, not for scroll.

Comment: You're life saviour! I was trying to customise LinearLayoutManager when I saw this solution. One question, is it possible to center align the items?

Comment: perfect, but there is no margin between items. how to solve that?

Comment: Easiest way to do that would be adding paddings into your child views

Comment: This works for androidx horizontally, but not vertically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the kotlin version of Mihail Ignatiev's Answer

```
class LinearLayoutPagerManager(context: Context,orientation: Int,reverseLayout: Boolean, private val itemsPerPage: Int) : LinearLayoutManager(context,orientation,reverseLayout) {

    override fun checkLayoutParams(lp: RecyclerView.LayoutParams?): Boolean {
        return super.checkLayoutParams(lp) && lp!!.width == getItemSize()
    }

    override fun generateDefaultLayoutParams(): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
        return setProperItemSize(super.generateDefaultLayoutParams())
    }

    override fun generateLayoutParams(lp: ViewGroup.LayoutParams): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
        return setProperItemSize(super.generateLayoutParams(lp))
    }

    private fun setProperItemSize(lp: RecyclerView.LayoutParams): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
        val itemSize = getItemSize()
        if (orientation == LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL) {
            lp.width = itemSize
        } else {
            lp.height = itemSize
        }
        return lp
    }

    private fun getItemSize(): Int {
        val pageSize = if (orientation == LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL) width else height
        return Math.round(pageSize.toFloat() / itemsPerPage)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked a while ago, but I've found a much simpler solution.

Just create your own LayoutManager and overwrite the method `getChildCount()`

The result should be something like this:

```
@Override
public int getChildCount() {
   return super.getChildCount() > 3 ? 3 : super.getChildCount();
}
```

That way, when you add this LayoutManager to the Recyclerview, it will just display 3 items at a time, no matter how many items the adapter has.

And, if you want a Pager like experience when scrolling just add a `SnapHelper`

```
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

Comment: This approach almost works, but results in incorrect layout with androidx.